# Why are declarations in a switch construct legal?

Tags: c++

I have found multiple questions regarding the subject of defining variables inside a `switch` construct, but I have not yet found a clear answer to this question.

Chapter 5.3.2 of the book C++ Primer says the following:

> As we’ve seen, execution in a switch can jump across case labels. When execution jumps to a particular case, any code that occurred inside the switch before that label is ignored.

Considering this information, I do not understand why the example below is legal. If control jumps to the `false` case, it should ignore the `true` case. This means that, assigning to `i` should be illegal, because it was never declared. Why is this construct legal?

```
case true:
    int i;
    break;
case false:
    i = 42;
    break;
```

Comment: Note: it's the same as: `goto label; int i; return; label: i = 42; return;`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Declaration is a compile-time thing, and what happens at runtime is irrelevant to that fact.  `i` is visible at any point *within the same or child scope* after its declaration.

There is nothing that causes a scope change between the two cases, so `i` remains visible in the `false` case regardless of whether the `true` case executed.

This is why you may see anonymous blocks (`{ }`) used to artificially constrain scope in switch cases.  It's to prevent exactly this potential issue (though in this case it's not an issue).

```
case true: {
    int i;
    break;
} // Closing this block causes the end of i's lifetime.

case false: {
    i = 42; // Compile-time error; i is no longer in scope.
    break;
}
```

Note that your code becomes illegal just by initializing `i`.  Jumps cannot cross over initialization in either direction.

```
case true:
    int i = 0;
    break;
case false: // error: jump to case label crosses initialization
    i = 42;
    break;
```

Also, any variable of a type that is *not* [trivial](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TrivialType) cannot have a lifetime spanning cases even if it is not explicitly initialized.

```
case true:
    std::string i;
    break;
case false: // error: jump to case label crosses initialization
    i = "42";
    break;
```

The fix in this case is to use anonymous blocks to constrain the scope the declaration of `i` to not span multiple cases.

---

The relevant standardese:

> It is possible to transfer into a block, but not in a way that bypasses declarations with initialization. A program that jumps* from a point where a variable with automatic storage duration is not in scope to a point where it is in scope is ill-formed unless the variable has scalar type, class type with a trivial default constructor and a trivial destructor, a cv-qualified version of one of these types, or an array of one of the preceding types and is declared without an initializer.

-- C++14 (N4296) [stmt.dcl.3]

The footnote (*) regarding jumps:

> The transfer from the condition of a `switch` statement to a `case` label is considered a jump in this respect.

Comment: The compile time vs runtime thing was exactly what made it click for me, thank you!